# SQL Server statements with IN clauses: how to make them faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I need to optimize the following query (table `group_attributes`) got columns `group_id`, `attribute_id` and `int_value`.

```
select  group_id 
from    group_attributes 
where   attribute_id= 1049 
        and int_value in (1247, 1248, 1249, 1250, 1251, 1252, 1253, 1254, 1255,
              1256, 1257, 1258, 1259, 1260, 1261, 1262, 1263, 1264, 
              1265, 1266, 1267, 1268, 1269, 1270, 1271)
```

that `group_attributes` is a huge table and the query takes forever.

I am not so much of expert in SQL so I wonder which query would work faster? It seems that in general these `IN` queries are damn slow.

Best, Askar

Comment: What indexes do you have in the table? Can you show the execution plan?

Comment: I would guess that an index on `(attribute_id, int_value, group_id)` would be efficient.

Comment: Just a matter of "style" probably, but in your special query you could use `int_value BETWEEN 1247 AND 1271`.

Comment: Indexes are: GA_ATTRIBUTE_ID_INDEX nonclustered located on PRIMARY ATTRIBUTE_ID
GA_GROUP_ID_INDEX nonclustered located on PRIMARY GROUP_ID
UQ_GROUP_ATTRIBUTES_TRX_ID nonclustered, unique, unique key located on PRIMARY TRX_ID

Comment: Marco, between ins unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Could you give me any command that I can perform on DB to get 'execution plan'?

Comment: [Displaying Graphical Execution Plans (SQL Server Management Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: It would be good if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statement in the question.

Comment: WHERE int_value BETWEEN 1247  AND 1271

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - I

I think you can improve the performance by creating following indexes.

1. Create Clustered Index on group_id
2. Non-Clustered index on (attribute_id,int_value)

Solution - II

You can also insert all int_values into a temp table and then create the non_clustered index on temp table. Also create non clustered index on int_value of main table.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, store all the required `int_values` to a Temp table and create a clustered index. Secondly, Inner join this temp table with `group_attributes` table.

This will give a better performance hopefully. Also please update the performance result.